# Tiered/grouped/layered FSM for deisning software?

Tags: design, finite-state-machine

Well in the past during education about integrated systems we've been thought a lot about FSM and how to design those. It was a good tool to "talk" about complicated systems and create a common baseline.

Now in an update to our application (some kind of webshop integrated into a lot of other tools), the "state" of the application also becomes "fuzzy" at times, while well defined it's difficult to talk about it. As such I wish to employ the techniques I notice about FSM.

However as I've used it FSM has a big "gab": it seems to very badly work with "layered" systems, or sub systems. In an FSM one should always design all states and for each input every state should have a well defined new state. This works with a few states and a few inputs, but what if the amount of states becomes larger, say a dozen or two?

Or when the input matrix becomes also larger with a lot of interconnected settings? I, a user has a log in state, but also a cookie acceptance state, and the items shown on the page depend on both of those (as well as other elements). Naively this would mean I'd have already many states: one copy for login status and for each cookie status, multiplied with the number of actual content pages.

Are there any techniques that allow fsm to become more scalable?

Comment: You would use the same techniques for scaling out a Finite State Machine as you would use to scale out any other computational system.

Comment: Well that would mean separating concerns, however that would mean there's no clear way to know if each input has a well defined path to an output. IE: say that I split the login state from the main state. Now the login state should become an "input" to the main state. However say that the main state can also act as input for the login system. Now the system might get into an oscillation.  With a single FSM one can easily see this when drawing the diagram, however when you have multiple they are black boxes to each other, so it's difficult to see other than manual reasoning.

Comment: FSM isn't appropriate for all situations. Think of a word processor.